# How many n-dimensional permutation matrices have all zeros along the diagonal?

Tags: linear-algebra, permutations

My question is inspired from this one in ILA 5th edition by Gilbert Strang:

If $a_{11}=a_{22}=a_{33}=a_{44}=0$, how many of the 24 possible products $a_{1j}a_{2k}a_{3l}a_{4m}$ are sure to be zero?

I found the answer for this case (15) but don't know how to solve in general for any size n.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: There seems to be some context missing; I would have assumed that $j$, $k$, $l$ and $m$ can all range from $1$ to $4$, so that there are $4^4=256$ such products.

Comment: @Servaes It seems the question is related to determinant.

Answer (score 4):

To generalize, suppose $a_{1,1}= a_{2,2} = \cdots = a_{n,n}  = 0$. Then how many permutations $\sigma$ of length $n$ are guaranteed to satisfy $a_{1,\sigma(1)}a_{2,\sigma(2)}\cdots a_{n,\sigma(n)} = 0$?

Essentially, we want the number of permutations which have a fixed point, i.e. $\sigma(k) = k$ for some $k = 1,\ldots,n$, since then $a_{k,\sigma(k)} = 0$, and so the product is guaranteed to be zero.

This is the opposite of a [derangement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement), which is a permutation $\sigma$ for which $\sigma(k) \neq k$ for all $k = 1,\ldots,n$.

The number of derangements of length-$n$ is given by $\text{round}\left(\dfrac{n!}{e}\right)$ (see the Wikipedia link for details), and so, the number of permutations which aren't derangements is $n!-\text{round}\left(\dfrac{n!}{e}\right)$.

For $n = 4$, you get $4!-\text{round}(\tfrac{4!}{e}) = 15$, as you computed.

Comment: I didn't know this way but I've derived the solution by a reccurence! Nice to know now.

Comment: thanks for the help! gotta learn about derangements now lol

Answer (score 2):

In general, for the determinant of a $n\times n$ matrix, we have $n!$ products.

Assuming that only the entries on the diagonal are equal to zero, it is not difficult to prove that the number of non zero product can be found by the [recurrence sequence](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=a%28n%29%3D%28n-1%29*%28a%28n-1%29%2Ba%28n-2%29%29%20for%20a%282%29%3D1%20and%20a%281%29%3D0)

$$a(n)=(n-1)\left[a(n-1)+a(n-2)\right]$$

with $a(2)=1$ and $a(1)=0$, which for $n$ from $1$ to $10$ leads to

[image]

therefore the number of zero product is given by $n!-a(n)$.

---

To see why the recurrence holds let consider the following sketch

[image]

then

- given a $n\times n$ matrix we have $n-1$ choices for the first row
- then we remain with a $(n-1)\times (n-1)$ matrix with a row and a column without zeros entries
- for this matrix the number of no zero product can be obtained considering at first the corresponding $(n-1)\times (n-1)$ with zero entries on the diagonal, which gives $a(n-1)$ not zero products, and then the remaining $(n-2)\times (n-2)$ matrix with zero entries on the diagonal, which gives a(n-2) not zero products

which leads indeed to

$$a(n)=(n-1)\left[a(n-1)+a(n-2)\right]$$

Comment: thanks for the solution!

Comment: You are welcome! The recurrence can be derived starting from the case $n=4$. For the first row we can choose $n-1=3$ entries then eliminating the first row and the column ofthe chosen entry we remain with a $3\times 3$ matrix which have a row with no zero.